# Is it possible to change the visibility of a window in MDM Zinc 4?

Tags: flash, zinc-4, mdm-zinc

I am working on a application in Flash AS3 with MDM ZINC 4 and I have to dynamically change the window property to be from a standard window in a transparent style with no border, and from there in a masked style window. I have searched the Live Docs for Zinc 4 but haven't found something useful.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into properties for "Window Properties" panel on the right side of Zinc Builder:
http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/4.0/index.php?url=help_docs.php?type=help%C2%ACpage=3
Under "style" and "type" section you could refine your application window look that will be used at runtime - including transparent, bordless and masked style.
Note that mask could be applied to application at runtime as well by calling method "showMask" of given form (window):
http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/4.0/index.php?url=main.php?action=methods%C2%ACclass=Forms%C2%ACid=9990
regards, 
Peter